# plot different size of circle with different color and label on the figure in R

Tags: r

I'm facing an issue with the following :

1- I don't know how to control the size of the circle, so the size should get larger when the number of groups in percent is large. For example, group1_north's first point is 97%(0.97) I want that to be a larger circle than 8.6%(0.086).

2- I don't know how to make each circle in a different color.

3- The label on the figure is very difficult to control, especially with long text. How to control the size and the wrap so it can be readable.

```
df=data.frame(names_of_dissess=c("Hib Disease_type1","Hepatitis_type1","Flu (Influenza)_type1","Ebola_type1",
                                 "Coronaviruses_type1","Japanese Encephalitis_type1"),
              algorithm1=c(0.00,0.29,0.11,0.21,0.25,0.29)
              ,group1_north=c(0.97,0.086,0.34,0.11,0.086,0.11)
             
              ) 

par( mar=c(6, 6, 4, 4),xpd = TRUE )

plot(group1_north ~algorithm1,
     col="lightblue",
     pch=19,
     cex=2,
     data=df,
     xlab = "algorithm1",
     ylab = "group1_north %",
     xlim=c(0.0,0.3),
     ylim=c(0.0,1),   
     main = "algorithm1 behavior",
     font.main=10,
     family = "A",
     cex.main=1.1,
     cex.lab=0.9
)  


text(group1_north -0.02 ~algorithm1, labels=names_of_dissess,data=df, cex.main =.9, font=8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R solution: See below for how to color and change size of points. Regarding positioning of text labels: my suggestion would to replace the text labels with a legend to avoid having to write a lot of code to position and size text labels in a way that is readable, which can get quite tedious. There are some packages such as `directlabel` and `ggrepel` that do this for you, but they do not work with ggplot, trellis and not base R plot objects

```r
df <- data.frame(names_of_disease = c("Hib Disease_type1", "Hepatitis_type1", 
                                     "Flu (Influenza)_type1", "Ebola_type1", 
                                     "Coronaviruses_type1", "Japanese Encephalitis_type1"), 
                algorithm1 = c(0.00, 0.29, 0.11, 0.21, 0.25, 0.29), 
                group1_north = c(0.97, 0.086, 0.34, 0.11, 0.086, 0.11)) 

par(mar = c(6, 6, 4, 4), xpd = TRUE )

plot(group1_north ~ algorithm1, 
     col = factor(df$names_of_disease), # use names_of_disease factor values to set point color 
     pch = 19, 
     cex = 10 * df$group1_north, # use group1_north as a scaling factor for point size
     data = df, 
     xlab = "algorithm1", 
     ylab = "group1_north %", 
     xlim = c(0.0, 0.3), 
     ylim = c(0.0, 1), 
     main = "algorithm1 behavior", 
     font.main = 10, 
     family = "A", 
     cex.main = 1.1, 
     cex.lab = 0.9,
     bty = 'n'
) 

# replace text labels with a legend
legend('topright', 
       col = factor(df$names_of_disease), 
       legend = df$names_of_disease, 
       pch = 19, 
       bty = 'n')
```

[image: diseases plot]

Comment: Thank you so much this is really helpful. I also have a question if you allow me If I want to add a new line in my data df like group1_south group1_south=c(0.94,0.086,0.37,0.14,0.086,0.11), then how can I plot this on the same figure with circles as well.

Comment: My pleasure. In order to answer your question, you'll have to be more specific: `lines(group1_south ~ algorithm1, data = df)` will give you a line... but not a straight one. You could also plot points `points(group1_south ~ algorithm1, data = df)` and then fit a linear model and draw the regression line: `lmgs1 <- lm(group1_south ~ algorithm1, data = df); abline(lmgs1, lty = 2, col = 'blue')`

Answer (score 2):

This uses ggplot2 and an extension. I didn't make the labels wrap, but you could add newline characters ("\n") within specific labels wherever you want them to wrap.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

df=data.frame(names_of_dissess=c("Hib Disease_type1","Hepatitis_type1","Flu (Influenza)_type1","Ebola_type1",
                                 "Coronaviruses_type1","Japanese Encephalitis_type1"),
              algorithm1=c(0.00,0.29,0.11,0.21,0.25,0.29)
              ,group1_north=c(0.97,0.086,0.34,0.11,0.086,0.11)
              
) 

ggplot(df, aes(algorithm1, group1_north)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = group1_north,
                 color = names_of_dissess),
             show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = names_of_dissess))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>